# Listbox show two time same values

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

i am using asp.net C# SQL to create a webpage.I need to list out a courseID to let user choose, but it list out two time same value in dropdownlist
S1111
S2222
S3333
S1111
S2222
S3333
,someone help

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        SqlConnection conn;
        SqlDataReader dtr;
        SqlCommand cmd;

        string Connnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ELearing"].ConnectionString;
        conn = new SqlConnection(Connnection);

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //Get Staff Information
            conn.Open();
            string cmdString = "SELECT DISTINCT CourseID FROM Schedule WHERE(StaffID = @scheduleStaffID)";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdString, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scheduleStaffID", Session["UserID"].ToString());

            dtr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dtr.Read())
            {
                ddlCourse.Items.Add(dtr["CourseID"].ToString());
            }
            dtr.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you run your query without the code in Sql Server Management studio, and using the ScheduleStaffId provided? Do you get duplicates then? So like SELECT DISTINCT CourseID FROM Schedule WHERE StaffId = 1

Comment: Have you tried `ddlCourse.Items.Clear` just before your `while` loop?

Comment: it work when i put ddlCourse.Items.Clear thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these

1.Do you get duplicates when you do *externally* SELECT DISTINCT CourseID FROM Schedule WHERE StaffId = 1

2.use breakpoints to check additional post backs.

3.Try ddlCourse.Items.Clear just before your while loop.